# d3 - add elements without append

Tags: d3.js

I have a demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vtqa8s?file=src/app/bar-chart.ts)

I have a stacked area chart with a mouseover that shows a tooltip with info for that area of the chart.

I'd also like to show circles onmouseover for the data points in that section.

I'm calling a function `showDataPoints` onmouseover and I'm passing the data for the section

```
function showDataPoints(data, block){
      let pointData = {};
      chartKeys.forEach(key => pointData[key] = data[key]);
      console.log(pointData)

      for(let p in pointData){
        //add circle use data for x pos
      }

      // const dataPoints = block.selectAll('circle')
      //   .data(pointData)

      //   dataPoints
      //     .enter()
      //     .append('circle')
      //     .classed('circles', true)
      //     .style('fill', 'black')
      //     .attr('r', 4)
      //     .attr('cx', (d) => this.x(d))
      //     .attr('cy', (d) => this.y(d))
    }
```

I cant get it to work with `.enter() .append()`

Is there a way to add circles without append

Comment: your `pointData` is an object, but `.data` takes an array

Comment: Where specifically do you want to show the circles at? What is the relationship between the `dataPoints` and the `circles`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From you original question, it's not clear what are your specific goals, but it seems like you wanted to use `pointData` as an `array` of data, so here is a draft of a possible answer:

```js
var chartKeys = ['one', 'two', 'three'];

function showDataPoints(data, block){
  let pointData = [];
  chartKeys.forEach(key => pointData.push({key: key, value: data[key]}));

  console.log(pointData)
  // prints out [{key: "one", value: 10}, {key: "two", value: 45}, {key: "three", value: 45}]


  const dataPoints = block.selectAll('circle')
     .data(pointData)

     dataPoints
       .enter()
       .append('circle')
    //using d in a function could be like d = {key: "three", value: 45}
}
```